# Word OpenXML . Traversing OpenXmlElements between bookmarks

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I need to traverse nodes between a bookmark start and a bookmark end tag.  The problem appears to break down into a tree traversal but I am having trouble pinning down the correct algorithm.  The bookmark start and end elements are non-composite nodes (no children) and may appear at an arbitrary depth in the tree.  Bookmark start are also not guaranteed to be a at the same depth.

If you draw the tree structure for the document I would want to examine all nodes between the start and end bookmark.  I think an algorithm to traverse an unbalanced tree starting at node x and ending at node y would work.  Does this sounds feasible or am I missing something.

If this is feasible could you point me in the direction of a tree traversal that could accomplish returning the nodes?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what you want to do, however, if you are primarily interested in the text between two bookmarks, then this is one of those cases where XmlDocument / XPath semantics are easier to use than LINQ to XML or the strongly-typed object model of the Open XML SDK V2.  The semantics of the 'following::*' axis of XPath is what you want.  The following example uses XmlDocument and XPath to print the names of the nodes between the start and end of a bookmark.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

class Program
{
    public static XmlDocument GetXmlDocument(OpenXmlPart part)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        using (Stream partStream = part.GetStream())
        using (XmlReader partXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(partStream))
            xmlDoc.Load(partXmlReader);
        return xmlDoc;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument doc =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open("Test.docx", false))
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = GetXmlDocument(doc.MainDocumentPart);
            string wordNamespace =
                "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr =
                new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("w", wordNamespace);
            XmlElement bookmarkStart = (XmlElement)xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("descendant::w:bookmarkStart[@w:id='0']", nsmgr);
            XmlNodeList nodesFollowing = bookmarkStart.SelectNodes("following::*", nsmgr);
            var nodesBetween = nodesFollowing
                .Cast<XmlNode>()
                .TakeWhile(n =>
                    {
                        if (n.Name != "w:bookmarkEnd")
                            return true;
                        if (n.Attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>().Any(a => a.Name == "w:id" && a.Value == "0"))
                            return false;
                        return true;
                    });
            foreach (XmlElement item in nodesBetween)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                if (item.Name == "w:bookmarkStart" || item.Name == "w:bookmarkEnd")
                    foreach (XmlAttribute att in item.Attributes)
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", att.Name, att.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've put together an algorithm that can easily retrieve the text of a bookmark.

[How to Retrieve the Text of a Bookmark from an OpenXML WordprocessingML Document](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/09/01/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-bookmark-from-an-openxml-wordprocessingml-document.aspx)

I've also written code to replace the text of a bookmark:

[Replacing Text of a Bookmark in an OpenXML WordprocessingML Document](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/09/06/replacing-text-of-a-bookmark-in-an-openxml-wordprocessingml-document.aspx)

-Eric

Comment: I think these links are dead.

Comment: They are dead.  SQL Server errors.  This is why good answers are never just links.